# Is Volttron a software gateway? How can it be used to transfer data coming over BACnet to Azure IoT hub over mqtt?

Tags: iot, volttron

Can https://volttron.org/ be used as a 'protocol translator gateway' software which can take data from PLC over BACnet/Modbus and can forward it to Azure IoT hub?
[image]
Where can I get demo for Volttron? I am new to python and unable to understand the code present related to Volttron. Office hours videos present on Volttron sites are not indicating if Volttron is a choice for my scenario shown in the image.

Please guide/help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VOLTTRON can be configured to retrieve bacnet traffic.  The picture you have drawn can be accomplished.

See
https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron

And
https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/main/

For instructions on how to use the platform.

In the picture volttron could actually be in either the PLC Controller (assuming it has enough capabilities) or the protocol translator gateway or both.  There is an mqtt facility in VOLTTRON to do the last step to the Azure IOT Hub as well, though it has not been tested with that interface.